# Convert a list of elements in a string

Tags: python

I've a list of names:

```
a = ['Maria','Luis','Andrea']
```

I want to put them in a string, so I make this:

```
names = ''
for name in a:
    names = names +',' ' ' + name
```

There's a problem, in the first iteretation I add a comma and a space at the beginning, I know I can just delete the comma and the space but I would prefer just to not have it.

Also, can that be done in a lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `str.join` method is for:

```
>>> ', '.join(a)
'Maria, Luis, Andrea
```

The method concatinates all the elements from an iterable with the string `join` is being called on as the separator.

Some examples:

```
>>> 'SEP'.join(a)
'MariaSEPLuisSEPAndrea'
>>> ''.join(a)
'MariaLuisAndrea'
```

It can be seen as the counterpart of `str.split`:

```
>>> s = ', '.join(a)
>>> s
'Maria, Luis, Andrea'
>>> s.split(', ')
['Maria', 'Luis', 'Andrea']
```

Answer (score 6):

Let the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) handle that:

```
>>> a = ['Maria','Luis','Andrea']
>>> ", ".join(a)
'Maria, Luis, Andrea'
```

Comment: Don't you feel just a little bit guilty answering obvious duplicates instead of voting to close them?

Comment: @cimmanon you definitely have a valid point. I don't go into general Python on SO often, when I do, I usually vote to close in similar cases, but here rushed into answering. So, yes, I feel guilty. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct pythonic way is the `",".join(...)` method given in the other answers. However the language agnostic method would be something like this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   if i == 0:
      names += a[i]
   else:
      names += ',' + a[i]
```